# How to use an enum in an Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular Components tend to have a global state (or "mode") so I am looking for a way to code this efficiently.  What I tried to do is this:

```
@Component({
      ....
})
export class AbcComponent implements OnInit {

  enum State {
    init, view, edit, create, wait
  }
  state: State = State.init;
```

The idea is that the functions inside AbcComponent can drive the template's operation simply by setting the **state** property.  For example:

```
<div class="col" *ngIf="state === State.view"> ... </div>
```

The problem is that the **enum** definition cannot appear inside the **class** structure.  And then if I move it outside the **class** structure then the template doesn't have it within its local scope.

Is there a different way to do this?

P.S. If it is of any interest what I have been doing is I have several **boolean** properties, one for each state.  For example **modeInit** **modeView** etc.   It works but it is clumsy because only one should be **true** at a time.

Comment: As the author of this question I am not interested in reopening the question because it was adequately answered by the marked answer.  However I fail to see how this is "opinion based."  This is a real problem which has a non-intuitive solution.  The use case of enum in Typescript templates is not obvious and the solution is not an opinion.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can define the `State` enum outside of the class, possibly in another file:

```
export enum State {
  init, 
  view, 
  edit, 
  create, 
  wait
}
```

and assign the enum to a public field in the class:

```
import { State } from "../models/app-enums.model";

@Component({
  ....
})
export class AbcComponent implements OnInit {
  public StateEnum = State;
  public state = State.init;
  ...
}
```

That public field can then be used to refer to the enum in the template:

```
<div class="col" *ngIf="state === StateEnum.view"> ... </div>
```

Comment: One might see it clearer with an imported alias. `import { State as StateEnum } from ...` so that class property would be `public State = StateEnum` and template would use `State` instead of `StateEnum`.

Comment: i forgot to use the export keyword and i didnot work. thanks

Comment: @AdoRen - One could also set `public State = State`, if the goal is to use `State` in the template.

Comment: One very important note is that the `export enum ...` has to be above `@Component`.

Comment: Also you can write down `public readonly stateEnum: typeof State = State`

Answer (score 5):

You can define a method or getter and compare your current state value with the enum already imported.  Like this:

```
import { State } from "../models/state-enum.ts";

@Component({
  ....
})
export class AbcComponent implements OnInit {
  private state: State = State.init;
  ...
  get isView() {
    return this.state === State.view;
  }
}
```

template.html

```
<div *ngIf="isView">Oh is view!</div>
```

Comment: Well if I wrap access to the property **state** I don't have to declare it in a separate file and import it.

Comment: Is it possible to move the function isView() to the enum declaration file? How could this method be accessed from HTML then?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use declaration merging to make the enum available as a static member of the component.

```
@Component({
    ....
})
export class AbcComponent implements OnInit {
    state = AbcComponent.State.init;
}

export namespace AbcComponent {
    export enum State {
        init, view, edit, create, wait
    }
}
```

and then access it in the template from the `constructor` field

```
<div class="col" *ngIf="state === constructor.State.view"> ... </div>
```

Comment: what is `constructor`? is it working? 
I have an error that no such `ng:Identifier`