# How to declare enum in Angular 8 component I am getting error while declare enum in angular 8

Tags: angular

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent   {
  enum AppStatus {  
    ACTIVE,  
    INACTIVE,  
    ONHOLD  
  }   

}
```

I am trying to use enum in component but gettting error
unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

Comment: How about adding `A constructor, method, accessor, or property` to your `AppComponent` class?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot declare an `enum` *inside* of a class. You need to do that separately:

```js
/* declare it here */
enum AppStatus {  
  ACTIVE,  
  INACTIVE,  
  ONHOLD  
}   

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent   {
  /* then you can use it here */
  appStatus: AppStatus = AppStatus.ACTIVE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the enum in a separate file, then import it into your component.

Check out this answer [How to use an enum in an Angular Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091786/how-to-use-an-enum-in-an-angular-component)